# Compiler compliance specified is 11 but a JRE 15 is used warning spring boot suite?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Installed JDK 1.8 and Spring boot suite. When I created my first project I got warning showing Compiler compliance specified is 11 but a JRE 15 is used in spring boot suite?
I checked preference->java-> Compiler and set it as 1.8. But still the warning shows

Comment: The ide might bring its own jre.

Comment: Did you check your pom.xml file? Which version of java does that have?

Answer (score 1):

For removing this error, right click on JRE System library and then click on properties at the exact bottom then change the execution environment to 15, then finally apply and close it,Warning will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did & it worked.
I checked the Eclipse features and verified the JDK is 15 but not 11. Since my SPring boot suite's internal JDk is 15, I had to download JDK 11 and add it to the JRE in Build path

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse from your project:

1. Right-click on your project
2. Click Properties
3. Java Compiler: compiler compliance level. Select the new "11" and apply the changes.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently, I show you the steps I followed to solve it:

1. Secondary button on the project
2. Properties
3. Java Compiler
4. Check "Enable project specific settings"
5. Adjust Compiler compliance level to the version number that is claiming you, for   example if you are using JRE 15 you leave this combo box at 15
6. Apply and Close

This solved my problem, good luck!